# Jquery updating value on screen, but not on submit ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a select function that gets the id from a selected row in my .js file and then sets its value to an input field in my razor view using Jquery. It shows the value on the form correctly, but when I submit the form the value isn't updated.

**Update:** I've updated this post to show how the data is being sent from ajax call. The selectable class is called when a row in a table is clicked. If anyone would like a reproducible example, I can add more code.

.selectable call from row click in **Event/Index.cshtml**

```
<tbody>
    @{int index = -1;
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        { 
            index++;
            <tr id="row_@item.EventId" class="selectable" controller="Event" Action="Selection" data-id="@item.EventId" data-index="@index">
                <td>@item.EventId</td>
                <td>@item.Type </td>
                //... <td>etc</td>
         }
    }
</tbody>
```

The selectable on click function gets the id of the selected row and passes it as the parameter to Event/EmployeeSelection

ajax call in **site.js** select function

```js
$((function () {
    $(".selectable").on('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault
        var selectedRow = e.target.parentElement;
        var id = $(selectedRow).data('id');
        var index = $(selectedRow).data('index');
        var controller = selectedRow.getAttribute("controller");
        var action = selectedRow.getAttribute("action");
        var url = "/" + controller + "/" + action + "/" + id;
        
        //... etc code to highlight rows here 
        
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {
                $(".selectionResult").val(response);
                $("#selectedId").val(id);
            }
        })
    });
}()));
```

Response from **EventController**

```c#
public JsonResult EmployeeSelection(int id)
{
    var selectedEmployee = _db.Employees.Find(id);
    return Json(selectedEmployee.Name);
            
}
/*the correct id is received here and the name of the corresponding 
 employee is returned to .selectable function as (response)*/
```

There are 2 submit buttons in my form so I am using formaction

Input and button in **Event/AddSchedule.cshtml**

```html
<input asp-for="Employee.Id" class="selectedId"/>
<button formaction="/Event/ScheduleEmployee" class="btn btn-primary" 
 type="submit"style="width:150px">Add To Schedule</button>

<!--the correct value of Employee.Id and Employee.Name appear in input
when selected, but values do are not updated in Network and not
submitted with other values that are not set dynamically -->
```

**/Event/ScheduleEmployee**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ScheduleEmployee(EventScheduleViewModel viewModel)
{
    //do something with viewModel etc
    return View("AddSchedule", viewModel);
}
//values not updated with .selectable appear in viewModel on submit
```

All of the inputs return their updated values to the controller action, except Employee.Id and Employee.Name which is given its value dynamically.

Comment: Your AJAX call doesn't appear to be sending any data

Comment: It sends it to the controller, and the values are updated in the view. What can I add to make the data submit?

Comment: How is the request routed? Do you have something like `[HttpPost("{id}")]`?

Comment: Also, use your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect the request. Perhaps you're calculating the URL incorrectly

Comment: Are you getting response from `selectedEmployee.Name`? Did you checked browser console? Where is your `submit` event?

Comment: Where is your `selectable` class? How your click event is triggered?

Comment: No I am not getting a response from selectedEmployee Name either. My selectable class in a in a row click event. I will just update my question with the necessary code. There are just a couple of moving parts. Also, when I check dev-tools, the value showing on the page is not updated in the Network. Whatever the old or original value of id is, is the value that the browser contains.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Action="EmployeeSelection"` in `Event/Index.cshtml`? Do you still have a `Selection` method in `EventController`? Also, I can receive a response that returns `selectedEmployee.Name`.

Comment: But I don't understand how to test next. How do you call `AddSchedule` and `ScheduleEmployee` methods after successful ajax call? Does ajax have any connection with these two methods?

Comment: AddSchedule is like a Get/Edit Action, it returns it's own view. The AddSchedule POST saves it's changes. There is a selectable list of Employees in the AddSchedule view. When you select an Employee their name and id appear as the input (what .selectable does). There are two other inputs in the form, a start time and end time. Schedule Employee is posted from a button in the AddSchedule view. It adds the selected schedule to a list of employee schedules for the given event. So there are 2 post actions related to AddSchedule, one to schedule employee shifts and one to save changes.

Comment: These are all in the Event Controller. The Event Index returns a list of Events. That table is also selectable. When an event is selected the user can edit it or go to a details/scheduling page where they add employee schedules to the event (AddSchedule). Selected and Selected Employee are both JSon Results in the Event controller, one is for selecting an event and the other is for selecting an employee. They both use the selectable function in site.js. I hope that is more clear. I will try to make a reproducible example.

Comment: It would be great if a reproducible example could be provided.

Comment: It was the employeeId. I was setting the selectedId as an id in js and it was a class in my razor page.